# Lubuntu 'Digital Clock' lags behind the system time

Tags: lubuntu

When I resume my laptop from sleep, the 'Digital clock' in the bottom right corner takes 10-15 minutes before it displays the correct time.

How can I increase the polling interval of the 'Digital Clock' application to have it pull up the system time more often?

I'm on Lubuntu 17.10 and synchronising the system time using Chrony. I know that the system time is correct as, on the terminal, the command 'date' shows the correct time.

Comment: Ignore my last comment.  Have you considered upgrading your Ubuntu?  17.10 is now EOL and it went EOL back in July.  Maybe 18.04 has the issue corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed in late 2017 by the LxQt developers:

https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/1245

If you upgrade and the problem persists I suggest adding to that bug report (as the LxQt developers have requested)

If you cannot update your system for whatever reason you can run this command when resuming to restart your desktop manager:

```
xfce4-panel -r && xfwm4 --replace
```

Comment: Good find thank you, I have not been updating as much as I should due to having all my coding projects on this machine. Looking at the source code that you linked to I'm 99% sure that this will fix the issue.